How should I respond to my peer requesting oversight for my admin role?
My colleague and I are both technical leads on sister projects. These projects share a repository, to which my colleague has the admin role but I do not. To properly perform my job I require the admin role, so today I contacted the IT department to request it, however they said they require written approval from one of the existing admins.
I contacted my colleague via IM asking him to send the approval email.
After vetting exactly what I was going to use the role for once it was granted, he agreed with my plan, but then asked me to confirm that I would not use admin again in the future without checking with him first.
I almost agreed to this stipulation, then gave it some more thought, and after a brief exchange I concluded that he should not grant me the admin role if he does not want me performing admin activities without his oversight. In my opinion, granting admin to somebody you do not trust to use it would be foolish and defeats the whole purpose of the admin role. I feel quite frustrated because I have vast experience administering repositories exactly like this, and am more knowledgeable in the technologies than he is. I also know from experience that often the times you need the admin role are during emergencies when seeking prior approval may not be feasible. It seems he did not like my response, and his final message said:

I am worried about you having admin access to the repo now

I am not sure what to do next, some options I'm considering are going over his head or even contacting HR. I also have the option to request approval from the other admin, who is unlikely to add such stipulations. My goals are:

To be able to properly perform my job
To lose the feelings of frustration towards my colleague
To avoid hurting my own career

What would be a good way for me to proceed?
Edit 1: The colleague in my question is also my line manager, but they are not responsible for my tasking, and we have the same seniority/job title, I have updated the question to try to prevent answers from confusing this as a chain-of-command issue
Edit 2: I highlighted to my direct report that I was blocked by lack of admin access, he immediately granted approval and seemed unhappy that my colleague had attempted to put stipulations on it. I believe goal 1 has been achieved but there is still uncertainty around goals 2 and 3.

"To lose the feelings of frustration towards my line manager" Only one person is in control of your feelings.

Sounds like a change management protocol (or lack of one?) more than anything else. Having gone though SOC-II, change management, including who does what as admin, should be well documented. Ask you manager if that is the intention.  @TheDemonLord ' s answer sounds like what is going on.

If this involves software, the fact that either of you needs admin access to the repository to perform your functions is a red flag for me from a security perspective.

What are the business reasons why you are objecting to having your admin changes reviewed with your line manager?

@DaveG Following unnecessary processes only leads to inefficiency, and the business requires me to be efficient. The process is demonstrably unnecessary because it doesn't exist. The other technical lead simply made it up on the spot. Plus I have been successfully leading projects for many years without any such process.

@Scroobius, it is your manager's responsibility to determine approved processes and reject inefficient processes. My advice is to be granted the admin role, prove your competency, and move on to the next task. It does not really matter how the individual became your manager; they are your manager and apparently currently the only administrator to the repository you need access to.

@Donald I'm not sure how you missed the bit in my question where I mentioned there being another administrator. The other administrator is actually senior to me, they are the person that is responsible for both projects. I am confident that they would happily grant me the admin role but I am hesitant to bypass the other technical lead after the way they ended the last conversation.

@Scroobius - I wouldn’t bypass your manager

I’m not quite following why you are surprised (alarmed? irritated?) by the response that they are worried about giving you admin access after you "concluded that he should not grant [you] the admin role if he does not want me performing admin activities without his oversight". I mean, you literally told them he should not give you the access you requested if he expects you to honour his request. If someone needs a security privilege from me and is not willing to follow my requirements then I would be worried too.

@Scroobius - I didn't miss that bit in your question, because it does not change the fact, the Administrator (one of them) is your manager. It does not change the fact you should NOT bypass your manager to gain access to the repository.

I think there may have been some wires crossed here
So, if I read this line:

but then asked me to confirm that I would not use admin again in the future without checking with him first.

Here is how I read this line:

Run any changes that require admin access past me in future

And this is pretty normal. Now, I want you to consider that he is your line manager - he is not your peer. Experience and ability aside, he is one level higher up as your direct manager and it is likely that he has responsibilities that you do not.
For example, he might be personally responsible for auditing any changes on the Repo - and therefore his request makes perfect sense.
Often times - when I have been granted god-mode or Admin rights to a new system, for the first few months - I am going to run any admin level changes passed the SME for that system as a matter of course - just to make sure that I am dialled in with their expectations. Typically I find that after this bedding in period - both myself and the SME are aligned on decision making and I can mostly work autonomously.
Emergency changes
I am going to cover this off separately. Sometimes shit happens - things are down and the boss is at lunch or uncontactable. In which case - I would do what was needed, then let my Boss know what was done (as sometimes things are changed in the course of testing or attempting a resolution that need to be reverted).
TL;DR - I think you over-reacted a bit - I would talk with your line manager and agree to the term, run things by him until he has the trust to let you free

So your answer seems to mostly pivot around the assumption that my line manager is a level higher than me. Most software engineers do not want to do the corporate management stuff, and my employer struggles very much to find enough managers. As such, they allow staff to line manage their peers, just like in my case where I'm a lead engineer being managed by another lead engineer. He does have responsibilities that I don't, such as timesheet approval and annual reviews, but I do not believe those are relevant to the question.

@Scroobius - your line manager IS at a higher level than you. You've confirmed it by saying they approve timesheets. Regardless how you feel about being more technically competent than them.

They approve timesheets because they responded "yes" to the regular emails going out saying "do you want to be a line manager?" We have the same job title. Regardless, I never said that I am technically more competent than them. They come to me to solve their problems with git, and the repository I'm talking about is a git repository. I am not claiming to be a better engineer overall.

@Scroobius sounds like if you want to be his peer, rather than one of his direct reports, then you need to respond "yes" to one of those emails too...

@PlayerOne sure, I got one last week, if I respond I can be approving timesheets by Friday. Will it make me more capable of administering the repository? Will it help the situation at all?

@Scroobius, I believe it is more an issue of official responsibilities and less of being capable of doing something.

@Scroobius the way I read this answer is that your line manager is the one who is going to be on the hook for any action you accomplish. This isn't about trust it's about accountability. If he's going to be accountable for what you do, then he has a definite right to be included in ratifying those actions.

@JoelEtherton If that was the case, I would understand completely. However, I am the technical lead of an independent project and accept responsibility for my own actions. He hasn't given me any reason to think that he's worried about being held responsible for any mistakes I make

@Scroobius does he have to? The situation obviously calls for it, and it's likely he's merely assuming that you're reasonable and understand the implications. Personally, from how you've chatted about it in comments throughout these threads, I think you have a cavalier attitude about the access. I expect people not to trust me when I'm asking for access. You should expect the same.

It may sound like your boss is stopping you from doing your job; in reality, he's a sanity check for any changes you propose making. I'd probably request the same, because it sounds like there is no audit procedure for your work at present.
I have admin rights to some quite (VERY!) important repos - which link to systems that you use every day.
If I want to merge changes into a repo - even if it's only a new comment - I need to create a merge request, and have it verified by another admin. This happens on a lower environment than prod. A special Production Deploy request is then made to move to prod - which needs signoff from my second level manager plus the affected users.
This is a solid system which you should consider using; nothing gets to prod without a minimum of three sets of eyeballs on it, and we have regression testing and monitoring behind it to ensure that the change doesn't cause any unexpected problems.

We do of course have audit procedures in place, there are redundant layers of quality control before anything goes near a formal release. We also have hard and fast rules like "all merge requests must be squashed" to prevent inexperienced team members from polluting the repository history, and occasionally we need experienced admins to bypass these restrictions for sensible reasons. Nobody is "sanity checking" the other technical lead and as I've said, I am more experienced at these things than he is.

What's wrong with keeping him in the loop when you need to use admin again? You guys share the repository. Sounds like you both don't trust each other. You both need to communicate better. Just get the admin privileges and keep him informed when you need to use it - it's not that hard.

He didn't ask me to keep him in the loop, he asked me to request permission. I trust him to continue using the admin role, and trust him to use his discretion to decide if he needs to inform me about something or not. I expect to see that trust returned.
